# How do I ignore parentheses while using string tokenizer to read in fractions?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

```
public Fraction (String fractionString)
{
  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fractionString, "/");
  numerator = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
  denominator = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
}
```

I have this so far.  How do I change this to ignore parentheses in a fraction?

Example: (3/4) - how do I ignore these parentheses?

Looking at this would I be able to simply do
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fractionString, "/()"?

Answer (score 2):

One way to ignore symbols such as `()+-*/` is to use one of the overloaded constructors for `StringTokenizer`.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fractionString, "()", false);
```

The `boolean` for the third argument denotes whether or not the tokenizer will put the given delimeters, in this case parentheses, into tokens themselves (`true`), or skip over them while tokenizing the rest of the string (`false`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace(char oldChar,char newChar)`

```
public Fraction (String fractionString)
{   
    fractionString = fractionString.replace("(","");
    fractionString = fractionString.replace(")","");
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fractionString, "/");
    numerator = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    denominator = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
}
```

Output from code:

```
(3/4)
numerator: 3    denominator: 4
```

Alternatively, you can use `.split(String regex)`as follows:

```
String[] split = fractionString.split("[()/]");
numerator = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
denominator = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
```